# vector crashes while trying to add string

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to add a string to vector but the program crashes while adding the string.Vector is declared in a seperate header file called customer.hpp and the implementation is in customer.cpp. In that file i am facing problem with addProductTocart function. Thanks in advance

Customer.hpp

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_HPP

#define CUSTOMER_HPP


#include "Product.hpp"

class Customer

{

private:

std::vector<std::string> carts;

std::string name;

std::string accountID;

bool premiumMember;

public:

Customer(std::string n, std::string a, bool pm);

std::string getAccountID();

std::string cusname();

//std::vector<std::string> getCart();

void addProductToCart(std::string);

bool isPremiumMember();

void emptyCart();

};

#endif
```

This is the function that i am passing string from

```
void Store::addProductToMemberCart(std::string pID, std::string mID)
{
    cout<<"adding to cart"<<endl;
     Customer *c=Store::getMemberFromID(mID);
     c->addProductToCart(pID);  

}
```

now for the crashing part.
while adding the string to the vector the program crashes

```
void Customer :: addProductToCart(std::string ID)
{

    carts.push_back(ID);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
Customer* Store:: getMemberFromID(std::string id) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) { 
        Customer c = members.at(i);
        if(c.getAccountID() == id) { return &c; } 
    } 
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `Customer *c=Store::getMemberFromID(mID);` return an invalid pointer (nullptr for example). Check it using your debugger.

Since you did not provide the implementation of `Store::getMemberFromID(mID)`,  we can not help more than that.

**Edit:**

After you have provided the implementation of `getMemberFromID`, It is obvouise that you are returning a pointer to stack allocated object that will be freed when it goes out of scope. You simply have undefined behaviour in your code.

**How to solve this?** you may change the implementation to something like this:

```
Customer* Store:: getMemberFromID(std::string id) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) { 
        Customer& c = members.at(i);
        //______^_______
        if(c.getAccountID() == id) { return &c; } 
    } 
    return NULL;
}
```

Anyway, this is not a good solution. Please consider redesigning your problem in a better way.

Comment: Customer* Store:: getMemberFromID(std::string id)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
    {
  Customer c = members.at(i);
        if(c.getAccountID() == id)
        {
      return &c;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
} this is the implementation of that

Comment: @user1210000 Better add that tidbit to the question with an edit. as you can probably see it is nigh-unreadable in a comment.

Comment: and Humam has nailed it. function returns a temporary copy of a value in the vector. Copy goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the function before the caller can use it. 10 points for Gryffindor.

Comment: i think its not the case because i tried to print the value inside the cart before exiting the function and it didnt even reach that part of the code.
So the program crashes while adding to vector

Comment: @user1210000, no this is the case exactly.. I have edited my answer

Comment: @user4581301 thanks,  they are a precious 10 for me :)

Comment: thankyou @HumamHelfawi it worked. I changed the code just like u suggested and it worked thankyou